# Can Xorg use non-square pixels? [or can we fake widescreen in a non-widescreen resolution?]

Tags: fedora, xorg, nvidia, monitors, resolution

I have an older PC connected to an HD television over VGA. The set of screen resolutions available for me to use are all 4:3 aspect ratio (or there abouts). Output from `xrandr`:

```
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 240, current 1280 x 960, maximum 1360 x 1024
default connected 1280x960+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024      50.0     54.0  
   1024x768       51.0     57.0     58.0  
   800x600        52.0     60.0     61.0     62.0  
   640x480        53.0     65.0     66.0     67.0  
   1280x960       55.0* 
   1152x864       56.0  
   832x624        59.0  
   640x512        63.0     64.0  
   576x432        68.0  
   512x384        69.0     70.0     71.0  
   416x312        72.0  
   400x300        73.0     74.0     75.0  
   320x240        76.0     77.0     78.0
```

Is there any way to use one of these resolutions, but treat the pixels as non-square? In much the same way as widescreen SD television image is stored at 720x576 (I'm in a PAL region) but anamorphically stretched to 1024x576; can I treat a resolution of 1280x960 anamorphically as ~1706x960?

Note: at present, the image is displayed in widescreen ratio, but this is a fake stretch. A drawing of a circle will display as an ellipse; I would like to utilise the full screen width, but retain the correct proportions for any images on display.

In case it affects any possible solutions, I am running Fedora 18, using an nVidia Geforce 5500 FX, Toshiba 37" 1080p LCD tv.